# Get Php String in jquery variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want following php string in jquery variable

```
{
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Seeing dads differently</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'> Roll up for the Social Science Market!</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Why do we use it?</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>'
}
```

Comment: This question needs some serious rewriting ...

Comment: is this php json string?

Comment: And I want Rolls-Royce Phantom.

Comment: Not json its simple php string

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php
    $phpstring = "{'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Seeing dads differently</a>','05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>','05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'> Roll up for the Social Science Market!</a>',
    '05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Why do we use it?</a>','05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>'}";
    $phpstring = json_encode($phpstring);

    echo "<script> var TestVar = $phpstring;</script>";
?>
```

Comment: @u_mulder, she said it is simple php string not json.

Comment: var Events = {
'10-17-2018' : '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Eaque molestiae assumenda necessitatibus alias dignissimos quod facere!</a>',
'09-22-2018' : '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Quo accusamus itaque esse aliquid error reprehenderit!</a>',
};
i want this in jquery.when i alert that variable i should get object object in alert

Comment: var Events = { '10-17-2018' : '<a href="google.com"; target=_blank>Eaque molestiae assumenda necessitatibus alias dignissimos quod facere!</a>', '09-22-2018' : '<a href="google.com"; target=_blank>Quo accusamus itaque esse aliquid error reprehenderit!</a>', }; i want this in jquery.when i alert that variable i should get [object Object] in alert

Comment: you said it is simple php string, then how do you get object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php variale in jquery like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var php_string;
    php_string = "<?= $phpstring ?>";
</script>
```